# Accepted meetings do not show up on my outlook calender

Tags: mac, email, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-office, calendar

I have been observing a weird behavior from my MS-Outlook on mac. What I am seeing is that  the meeting invitations that I get and accept, do not show up on my Mac Outlook calendar. Now the fact that I received a meeting invitation and I accepted could be traced when I look at my sent items, I can see that I sent a meeting acceptance.

Also, I have the same account on my outlook on my iPhone and I can see there that the meeting is on my calendar. There is something definitely something missing my my outlook on Mac. Not sure what could it be. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried to delete your outlook profile and create a new one? Have you checked in to [sync issues](https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&source=web&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwi93s2p9pLkAhXJUt8KHadBCycQzPwBegQIARAC&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.howtogeek.com%2F377695%2Fview-and-delete-sync-issues-in-outlook%2F&psig=AOvVaw1nUthwDTXZlCoKDWPzQMXe&ust=1566441195900325)?

Comment: I just had the same issue. I accepted an invite, then accepted again from the deleted invite. Now the item isn't on my calendar, and isn't in deleted items. The only reference I have to it is in the Sent folder. Had to create a new local event to remember to go!

Comment: I have a similar issue - it seems to be related to "sleep" mode. Quitting and restarting Outlook after wake-up significantly reduces the issue frequency.

Answer (score 0):

If you can see the meeting on iPhone or web mail, you’ve succeeded to accept the meeting, but it is invisible on Outlook for mac.

This could be related with corrupted view. Can you see your appointments if we switch to other view? Try switching between the Day/Work Week/Week/Month view.

See if all Categories is selected:

[image]
[image]

Please also go to Preferences > General, make sure the "Hide On My Computer folders" option is unchecked.

If none of this helps, then create a new profile: [Manage profiles or identities in Outlook for Mac](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/manage-profiles-or-identities-in-outlook-for-mac-fed2a955-74df-4a24-bef6-78a426958c4c)